# Prevent a part of the caption from appearing in the list of figures

Tags: floats, captions

I am using the 'article' class, 'figure' environment.

My captions are divided in two parts:

- the information about the figure
- the credits of the figure (for which I use `\textfff{}`)

In my list of figures, I would like to omit the second part. Would you have a solution, please?

Comment: What does the `\textfff` macro do?

Comment: I meant \texttt{} :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the optional argument of the caption command:

```
\caption[caption_for_list_of_figures]{full_caption}
```